# What is used in Nodejs - Sequelize for removing spaces when insert in DB using

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've used `Trim()` method to remove spaces from data before insert in DB. I'm using Nodejs and Sequelize. But is there something that is used to do that and for example if I have array, to pass this array, not to loop through all elements to strip spaces?
Thanks.

Comment: perhaps your specific db can help with this at the sql level. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571180/auto-trim-database-entries

Comment: I'm using Mysql. I'm not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mysql trigger that will trim your field on insert

Create them for each of the fields you want trimmed.

I verified this is working on mysql workbench.

Create a mysql trigger that will trim your field on insert

Create them for each of the fields you want trimmed.
Example:

I verified this is working on mysql workbench.

Source : [Automatically trimming CHAR data on insert into VARCHAR column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159764/automatically-trimming-char-data-on-insert-into-varchar-column)

Code:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
 CREATE TABLE tmp ('txt' varchar(50));
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_tmp;
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_tmp BEFORE INSERT ON tmp FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.txt=TRIM(NEW.txt);
 INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ("        abc   "), ("efg      ");
 SELECT txt, LENGTH(txt) FROM tmp;`

Comment: Thank you. I've just tested it in Phpmyadmin and it is working. I only used query to create trigger cause I have existing table.